# AWS: Creating a shared websocket between multiple EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

I'm using EC2 container service to host a cluster of instances of my server on AWS. So, when a user connects to the website, they could be on one of three EC2 instances. If I have a websocket between a client and the server, that seems to be fine.

But say I want to play, for example, Tic Tac Toe between two users. If they both connect to websockets, but are actually on different EC2 instances, will they share the same connection, or will they be isolated? Is there some way I can make sure that they are on the same instance, or do I need to set up some external machine that just hosts websockets, that can be a single location that all the clients on multiple instances can connect to?

Comment: You might want to adjust your architecture so that users don't have to be on the same EC2 instance to play tic tac toe.  You should represent your tic tac toe games in some backend storage system that is accessible to all your nodes, rather than having the game's state be represented only in DOM.  That way, you might have half a chance of recovering from any broken web sockets too.  People might not mind losing their uncompleted tic tac toe games when their wifi goes down, but real applications need to be more robust than that.

Comment: @DanFarrell thanks for your reply. Maybe my question wasn't clear, but that's what I'm trying to do - make it so users don't have to be on the same EC2 instance to both open web socket connections on the same server. The tic tac toe example might not have been ideal, because you could pro

Comment: (i can't edit my own comment for some reason) ...probably do that with some storage system, and just query that occasionally to get moves. I actually need the instant broadcasting of websockets.

Comment: @bermudacake Did you found out an answer for your situation